# Phonegap iphone device not find the www/Shelf/index.html

Tags: iphone, cordova, device

I make a phonegap alpplication, which display offline pages. These sites are in subdirectory of www.

For example:

```
www/ListView/index.html
www/Login/index.html
www/Shelf/index.html
```

When I build the application on iPhone simulator and the start page is www/Shelf/index.html everything is perfect.
When I install (jailbreak iphone) the application to the device I have the following message:

```
ERROR: Start Page at 'www/Shelf/index.html' was not found.
```

BUT if I don't modify the original www/index.html start page, then everything is displayed on the device and the simulator.
Any Ide?
Thank you in advance for your help!

Balazs

Answer (score 2):

It's a common issue in xcode. Drag your www folder into your xcode executable sdk. For further information chk the link.[Go to the link for xcode application](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xbZq5ckN5cQ)

Answer (score 0):

try editing 
`+ (NSString*) startPage
{
    return @"index.html";
}`
to

`+ (NSString*) startPage
{
    return @"Shelf/index.html";
}`

in phonegapdeligate.m file in phonegap's library

Comment: I tried it but no. When I open the application on the Device there is the same error message, what is come in the question.

Comment: I find the answer: When I upload the application on the device every directory in the application is 700. The right is 755. It's fine. Thanks the answer.